# NodeJS - failed to read newly uploaded file

Tags: ajax, node.js, file-upload, express

I was trying to build a system (NodeJS + Express 4) that reads a user uploaded text file, process it, and feed it back to the user. I was trying to use ajax upload, and multer as the parser for multi-part data. The whole workflow is supposedly to be like this:

1. User chooses a local file, and clicks the upload button.
2. Server received file, and read it.
3. Server do some processing with the data
4. Send results back

Every part of the link works except the server read part - sometimes the file is not read fully even though the server signals that the file upload was completed (I have tried multiple libraries, like multer, busboy, formidable that triggers the file upload complete event). I have done various experiments, and here's what I find (with 1000 lines of file):

1. the fs.readFile sometimes ends prematurely. The result file can be anywhere between 100 - 1000 lines.
2. missing part is almost always the last small piece, feels like the pipe was not fully flushed yet. I have tried file size between 1000 lines to 200,000 lines, and it's always missing the last few hundred lines.
3. using streaming almost solved the issue - like createReadStream, or byline, line-by-line, but sometimes the result can be 'undefined' or missing the last few lines, but a lot less frequent.
4. trigger the read twice, and the second time is almost guaranteed to read the full 1000 lines.

Is there anyway to force NodeJS to 'flush' the uploaded file? Somehow I feel the upload complete event was triggered (regardless of library, and everyone is dependent on FileSystem I guess) before the last piece of file was flushed in the stream. Or maybe there are some other issues - reading a static files always give the correct results. I could use the http POST forms but I'd like to use ajax to improve user experience.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I did some more experiment, it seems that sometimes file are not fully uploaded ... I am using FormData. Any reason why file may not be uploaded fully?

Comment: It's hard to say without any code to reproduce.